# Django - is it required to use/overwrite form_valid() when using CBV?

Tags: django

I'm using the below class based view in `Django` in order to be able to create/insert new object in the database which works:

```
class AddAreaMapView(CreateView):
    model = AreaMap
    fields = ['fCityCode',
              'fCountyCode', 'fCountryCode', ]
    template_name = 'myapp/blank.html'
    success_url = '/'
```

However, I've seen that there is recommended to use `form_valid()` method together with the `CreateView`. Why is it required to overwrite it since `Django` is already doing that? Is a missing piece of information and I would appreciate if anyone could provide a relevant answer. Thanks!

Comment: **No**, by default it will redirect to the success_url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is it required to overwrite it since Django is already doing that?

**It is *not***. In the Django documentation, the [example [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.CreateView) does *not* contain an override for the `form_valid`.

The `form_valid` that is used is the one provided by the [**`ModelFormMixin`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.ModelFormMixin). For the [**`form_valid`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.ModelFormMixin.form_valid) it will:

> **Saves the** form **instance**, sets the current object for the view, and **redirects to `get_success_url()`**.

The [**`get_success_url()`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.ModelFormMixin.get_success_url) will:

> Determine the URL to redirect to when the form is successfully validated. Returns **`django.views.generic.edit.ModelFormMixin.success_url` if it is provided**; otherwise, attempts to **use the `get_absolute_url()`** of the object.

So if you provide a `success_url`, it will redirect to that url. If you do not provide a `success_url` (or override the `get_success_url` method), it will aim to take the [**`get_absolute_url()`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/instances/#get-absolute-url) of the object.

Comment: Thanks. I do not have enough reputation to up-vote the answer but I will accept it. This logic applies for the `UpdateView` as well, right?

Comment: @nocoder: yes. The `UpdateView` makes use of the same `ModelFormMixin`.

Comment: Could you please point me to some docs or examples of when it is absolutely necessary to overwrite `form_valid()`?

Comment: @nocoder: when you want to add extra/other behavior when the form is valid. For example if you want send a notification to the user, etc. This is however often done by adding extra mixins, like the `SuccesMessageMixin`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/messages/

Comment: @nocoder one common example of overriding `form_valid()` is to link the saved object to the logged-in user ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#models-and-request-user))